# Out-of-the-box Semantic Highlighting IDE or text/code editor

Tags: text-editor, ide

After reading ["***A case against syntax highlighting***"](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/syntaxhighlighting/), I started looking for an IDE or text/code editor that comes with that option as part of its default options, but didn't have luck - seems like the only way to get this is by installing plugins or add-ons to the usual editors: `vim`, `emacs`, `netbeans`, `brackets`, `lighttable`, etc...

Is there an IDE or text/code editor that comes with Semantic Highlighting as part of it, without having to install additional stuff?

Some details regarding the wanted functionality:

- The OS is not a restriction, but of course that cross-platform is better.  Web editors are ok too.
- Free/OSS is preferred, but it's not a restriction either.
- I'm looking for Web and *Dynamic* languages support, specifically Javascript and Python.
- Intellisense support would be great, but not a must.
- If you can run commands from the IDE to a terminal, that would be great too.

Comment: jim, cross-posts are frowned upon on SE. Second, please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) – either my eyes are not open wide enough, or you missed even stating the OS you're targeting ;)

Comment: @Izzy, you are right - I deleted the cross post in SO and updated my question.  Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Thanks, jim! Additionally, you might wish to include a list of your requirements. Specifically: What syntax should be supported (reading *between* the lines I guess "Java" because of netbeans, but I might be wrong), what other features should be available? The better you can describe it, the higher are the chances for really good answers matching your needs.

Comment: What do you mean by "Semantic" highlighting?  Most editors are completely clueless about semantics.

Comment: My [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24908472/802365)/[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24908510/802365) on Stackoverflow has a list of editors supporting Semantic highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

From my own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24908472/802365)/[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24908510/802365) on Stackoverflow, here is the list of editor supporting Semantic highlighting.

- Atom.io

  - [language-javascript-semantic](https://atom.io/packages/language-javascript-semantic) by Philipp Emanuel Weidmann
- Emacs

  - [color-identifiers-mode](https://github.com/ankurdave/color-identifiers-mode) by Ankur Dave
  - [rainbow-identifiers](https://github.com/Fanael/rainbow-identifiers) by Fanael
- [kDevelop](https://zwabel.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/c-ide-evolution-from-syntax-highlighting-to-semantic-highlighting/)

  - Semantic Highlighting the original implementation/invention
- Sublime Text

  - [Sublime-Colorcoder](https://github.com/vprimachenko/Sublime-Colorcoder) by vprimachenko ;
- XCode

  - [Polychromatic](https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/Polychromatic) by Kolin Krewinkel
- Vim

  - [Semantic Highlight](https://github.com/jaxbot/semantic-highlight.vim) by jaxbot

Feel free to edit to add new editors.

Comment: Édouard, we don't favor "listings" here – posts like that are, in context of *this site*, rather considered "low quality". Answers here on SR should recommend software for the specific requirements, and thus show how they meet those, and what makes them especially recommendable. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it might be removed.

Comment: @Izzy splitting the answer to have one IDE per answer should be done by people with more knowledge than I have on each of this software. I'm just providing a list of possibility, that's not the ideal answer but best on this topic as it give you directions to explore.
I reckon providing such list will help people decide by themselves by removing the hassle to do multiple searches to find the possibles. Anyway, I won't fight for this answer, I'm just trying to contribute until someone improve or provide a better answer (stub > nil).

Comment: I see the reasoning, but that's not how this site works. Can you at least describe one of the applications in the list in a way matching this site's rules? Then keeping the others as "possible alternatives" should be OK. As the answer is a 1:1 copy of another post at SO, it'd otherwise better be a comment containing that link.